# MassTransit Consumer Release Patterns

Tags: masstransit

Is it possible to do modern release patterns using MassTransit Consumers

- Blue / Green
- Canary

We know that MT allows for Round-Robin releasing if the same consumer is running in multiple instances. For example where we have 2 instances running in a K8s Cluster, the work load will be automatically shared between all 2 running instances.

This process gives us a 50%/50% Canary release however, we would like to release to only 5%/95% and slowly increase as we gain confidence in the new version.

I am looking to allow the teams to release using Canary releases but I can't see any examples, code or tests that can enable this.

Is this possible with MassTransit?

Comment: There isn't a great answer on this one – blue/green deployments with message brokers is just complicated. It isn't like HTTP where the load balancer can shunt 5% of the traffic to the new instance and monitor error rates.

Comment: Would implementing a Saga that delegates traffic to sub consumer (blue/green) be a bad/good idea? Traffic management settings can be stored in Redis. However, every call would have two hops (Producer > Saga > ConsumerA) / (Producer > Saga > ConsumerB)